# Discord.js How i sent welcome message to new member join guild?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

## Discord.js Version 11.4.2

How i sent welcome message to new member join guild?

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [guildMemberAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) to do send welcome message to member `guildMemberAdd`

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  await member.send(Embed);
});
```